# How to edit a ScrollView from inside a View in Xcode4?

Tags: view, interface-builder, uiscrollview, xcode4, scrollview

How can I properly edit a a ScrollView that is a child of a View in Xcode 4.

I have a really long ScrollView (over two pages with lots of controls) and XCode does not let me see the entire scrollview when it is embedded in a View xib.

How am I supposed to be able to edit the ScrollView in interface builder?

[image: xcode scrollview inside a view]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're taking the correct approach (as per [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252503/scrolling-through-uiscrollview-in-interface-builder-for-xcode-4)) you just edit it side-by-side like you have in your screenshot and then nest the scrollview back into the view before running the app.